# Why can't I have two "oninput" listeners on javascript?

Tags: javascript

I created two inputs with the ids `name` and `age`, and I've been trying to check if data was inserted in them by using javascript's `oninput`, it worked for `age` but not for `name`, what am I doing wrong?

```js
var name = document.getElementById('name');
var age = document.getElementById('age');
age.oninput = function() {
  console.log('age');
  return true;
};
name.oninput = function() {
  console.log('name');
  return true;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>clerf</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <input type="text" id="name" />
    <input type="number" id="age" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Attach event listeners instead

Comment: @ElGavilan Thanks but I'd like to know why this is happening, and why I can't use two `oninput`s

Comment: Try using an ID other than `name`. I believe that it's reserved or that the Window object has dibs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because [`name` already exists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name). Give it a different name and it will work just fine.

```js
var nameEl = document.getElementById('name');
var age = document.getElementById('age');
age.oninput = function() {
  console.log('age');
  return true;
};
nameEl.oninput = function() {
  console.log('name');
  return true;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>clerf</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <input type="text" id="name" />
    <input type="number" id="age" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `window.name` is the name given to a popup (via passing to `open()`) or iframe (via `name="something"` attribute), all `window`s have it, even if by default it's `""`. `window.name` also MUST be a String, and it persists between reloads, and it's persisted on different sites recycling the same tab.

Answer (score 0):

Name seems to be <del>a keyword</del> an existing property of `window` (as in `window.name`) and thus it's already taken.

Change it to `nameEl` and it works

*(updated based on comments)*

```js
var nameEl = document.getElementById('name');
var ageEl = document.getElementById('age');

nameEl.oninput = function() {
  console.log('name');
  return true;
};

ageEl.oninput = function() {
  console.log('age');
  return true;
};
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <input type="text" id="name" />
  <input type="number" id="age" />
</div>
```

**PS**
Thanks to @Xufox and @DanDavis for their comments

Comment: `name` is definitely not a keyword. It’s a `window` property which can’t be redefined.

Comment: @Xufox: window.name can be redefined to any string, it's the cross-domain "name transport":  `window.open(someOffSiteUrl, "some secret")`, in popup:`alert(name)`

Comment: got me, thanks... perhaps 'keyword' was a poor choice of words - I meant an existing property name - will update my answer FWIW

Comment: I meant “redeclared”.